# How to capture (the type of) prelude exceptions?

Tags: haskell, exception, ghc

Say I do the following from ghci:

```
   Prelude Control.Exception Data.Typeable> let a = read "A" :: Int
   Prelude Control.Exception Data.Typeable> a
   *** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
```

Great! Now I just need to somehow know the type (and the module) of this exception to write an exception handler. Is there any way to get said type and module?

Comment: You didn't ask, but it might be worth pointing out that the standard way to deal with parse failures is to use `readList` rather than calling `read` and then trying to catch the exception.

Comment: @MathematicalOrchid Thanks! I ended up using readEither and I will check out readList now. But it is not the first time that I hit the wall against relatively hidden exceptions, so chi's answer is priceless.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Built upon Daniel Wagner's answer:

```
import Control.Exception
import Data.Typeable

whichException :: IO a -> IO ()
whichException act = do
  e <- try act
  case e of
    Left (SomeException ex) -> print $ typeOf ex
    _                       -> putStrLn "No exception occurred"

-- Usage:
-- > whichException (evaluate (read "A"::Int))
-- ErrorCall
```

Answer (score 4):

We know `read` comes from `Prelude`. So we can look at the [`Prelude` documentation for `read` on Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:read), which includes a [source link](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/src/Text.Read.html#read). From there, you can keep clicking on the error-y-looking part to follow the `read`-`error`-`errorCallException`-`ErrorCall` chain and learn that the appropriate exception to catch is `GHC.Exception.ErrorCall`. Testing in ghci:

```
> try (evaluate (read "A")) :: IO (Either ErrorCall Int)
Left Prelude.read: no parse
```

Seems to work!

Comment: Thanks. A bit dissapointed that there is no magic bullet, but this will do!!